# Which reasons may cause low MHz of CPU

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-frequency, lscpu

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.3. I installed it just now and executed some processes on it. I found that many processes used more than 100% CPUs. However, when I executed `lscpu | grep MHz`, I got the output as below:

```
CPU MHz: 423.687
CPU max MHz: 2200.0000
CPU min MHz: 800.0000
```

If I'm right, `CPU MHz` is the current MHz, so this is weird. Why can the current MHz be lower than `CPU min MHz`, even if some processes have used more than 100% CPUs?

Comment: Load is not cpu. What does vmstat say?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   vmstat looks good. `free` is large enough, `buff` and `cache` are reasonable, `swpd` is small.